# Passing a state which has an object to another Sibling components in React and mapping it

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I am using a state to store an object which is like

```
const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([{ lessonName: "", lessonDescription: "" }]);
```

so that i could map it in a table using     {inputList.map(lessons)}. in another sibling component.

I initialized the state in the sibling component.

```
    const {inputList} = props;
    const lessons = (inputs,index) => {
    return (
      <tr key ={index}>
        <td>{inputs.lessonName}</td>
        <td>{inputs.lessonDescription}</td>
        <td onClick={handleShow}><AiOutlineUpload  fill='blue'/><sup>  </sup>Add  Content</td>
      </tr>
      )
  }
```

But now  when i am trying to map it in the table using

```
<tr>
          {inputList.map(lessons)}
      </tr>
```

it says inputList is undefined.

Comment: Declare the state on the parent component and pass the "setState" function and the State to both children as props. Then you could change the state from each children and affect the sibling.

Comment: @BlowFish Yeah i did that and i have edited my question i am still unable to map it as it says it is undefined.

Comment: Your code you provided can not find problem. Could you provide an online demo, such as https://codesandbox.io/,  It better way to find problem.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-spence-b2kg7?file=/src/App.js  I am trying to pass inputList from LessonInfo to LessonList component. The demo might not work here but it's working in my localhost as it'sa  part of a bigger repository.  What changes should i make so inputList renders properly?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-resonance-p64ye

You need to declare the state and method to update the state in your parent component in this case Form.js

```
setInputList = (newState) => {
    this.setState({
      inputList: [newState]
    });
  };
```

You will need to pass the method and state to the child components

```
switch (step) {
      case 1:
        return <CreateCourse nextStep={this.nextStep} />;
      case 2:
        return (
          <LessonInfo
            setInputList={this.setInputList.bind(this)}
            nextStep={this.nextStep}
            prevStep={this.prevStep}
          />
        );
      case 3:
        return (
          <LessonList
            inputList={this.state.inputList}
            nextStep={this.nextStep}
            prevStep={this.prevStep}
          />
        );
      default:
        return null;
    }
```

in the component that updates the state you will create a function to handle the data and send it to the state. I use a button with this funciont on the onClick event.

```
const setInputList = (e, arg) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const object = {
      lessonName: arg.lessonName,
      lessonDescription: arg.lessonDescription
    };
    props.setInputList(object);
    
  };
```

In the component rendering the state will use something like this to call the state and render it making sure is not undefined.

```
{inputList?.map((lesson) => (
                    <>
                      <td>{lesson.lessonName}</td>
                      <td>{lesson.lessonDescription}</td>
                    </>
                  ))}
```

Make sure that the state is an array of object so you can use the map function.